# Use CXX to query preprocessor defines?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a GNUmakefile that respects `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`. It also performs some platform and architecture tests. Currently, the makefile assumes the host and target are the same:

```
IS_X86 = $(shell uname -m | $(EGREP) -c "i.86|x86|i86|amd64")
```

In an effort to improve robustness, I want to ask the tools what it is compiling for. I've come up with the following, but I'm not sure it is correct.

```
$ export CXX=clang++
$ export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -m32"
$ $CXX $CXXFLAGS -dM -E - < /dev/null | egrep "(i386|x86_64)"
#define __i386 1
#define __i386__ 1
#define i386 1

$ export CXX=clang++
$ export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3"
$ $CXX $CXXFLAGS -dM -E - < /dev/null | egrep "(i386|x86_64)"
#define __x86_64 1
#define __x86_64__ 1
```

My question is, will the above - with `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` - work reliably to detect a target? Or do I need something else?

---

Here's the two reasons I ask. First, my experience with Autotools indicates something different. When Autotools performs a test like above, they test `CPP`, and sometimes `CPP` or `CXX` needs to include `--isysroot` (or other hacks) to get things configured properly.

Second, some toolchains, like Clang, integrate other components (like a preprocessor or assembler), so I can't use `CPP` directly under all circumstances.

In fact, doing something as simple as `$CXX -Wa,-v - </dev/null` (ask assembler for its version) results in an "unsupported option" error under Clang when using its integrated assembler. (Cf., [With integrated assembler enabled, fail to fetch version string of assembler](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24200)).

---

And just in case: this is not an Autools or Cmake project. It does not use Boost or any other libraries. Its a stand alone C++03 project.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, will the above - with CXX and CXXFLAGS - work reliably to detect a target?

The answer is *Yes*, it will. The preprocessor or compielr driver (passing down to preprocessor) will mostly yield expected target defines with all else being equal. Notable exception is [GCC and ARMv8/Aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37066261), which is missing a slew of expected defines.

The thing to avoid is `uname -m` (and friends). Uname reports information on the host, and not the target.