# Why is __ARM_FEATURE_CRC32 not being defined by the compiler?

Tags: c++, arm, c-preprocessor, neon, intrinsics

I've been working on this issue for some time now, and I hope someone can point out my mistake. I guess I can no longer see the forest through the trees.

I have a [LeMaker HiKey](http://www.lenovator.com/product/86.html) dev board I use for testing. Its AArch64, so its has NEON and the other cpu features like AES, SHA and CRC32:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
Processor   : AArch64 Processor rev 3 (aarch64)
...
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 
...
```

When I attempt to compile a program:

```
$ cat test.cxx
#if (defined(__ARM_NEON__) || defined(__ARM_NEON))
# define NEON_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE 1
#else
# define NEON_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE 0
#endif

#if BOOL_NEON_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE
# include <arm_neon.h>
# if defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRC32) || (__ARM_ACLE >= 200)
#  include <arm_acle.h>
# endif
#endif

#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  uint32_t crc = 0;

  crc = __crc32b(crc, (uint8_t)0);
  return 0
}
```

It results in the following:

```
$ g++ test.cxx -o test.exe
test.cxx: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cxx:20:33: error: ‘__crc32b’ was not declared in this scope
   crc = __crc32b(crc, (uint8_t)0);
                                 ^
test.cxx:22:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^

$ clang++ test.cxx -o test.exe
test.cxx:20:9: error: use of undeclared identifier '__crc32b'
  crc = __crc32b(crc, (uint8_t)0);
        ^
test.cxx:21:11: error: expected ';' after return statement
  return 0
          ^
          ;
2 errors generated.
```

A grep of the file system reveals `arm_acle.h` is in fact the header:

```
$ grep -IR '__crc32' /usr/lib
/usr/lib/gcc/.../include/arm_acle.h:__crc32b (uint32_t __a, uint8_t __b)
...
```

And according to [ARM® C Language Extensions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0053c/IHI0053C_acle_2_0.pdf), Section 9.7 *CRC32 Intrinsics*, the missing symbols are suppose be present when `__ARM_FEATURE_CRC32` is defined. Inspecting `arm_acle.h` confirms it.

For completeness, I tried compiling with `-march=native`, but the compiler rejected it.

Why is `__ARM_FEATURE_CRC32` not being defined by the compiler?

What can I do to get the program to compile with the native features available on the board?

---

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian/Linaro 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ clang --version
Debian clang version 3.5.0-10 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

---

```
$ g++ -dM -E - </dev/null | egrep -i '(arm|neon|acle)'
#define __ARM_NEON 1

$ clang++ -dM -E - </dev/null | egrep -i '(arm|neon|acle)'
#define __ARM_64BIT_STATE 1
#define __ARM_ACLE 200
#define __ARM_ALIGN_MAX_STACK_PWR 4
#define __ARM_ARCH 8
#define __ARM_ARCH_ISA_A64 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_PROFILE 'A'
#define __ARM_FEATURE_CLZ 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_DIV 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_FMA 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_UNALIGNED 1
#define __ARM_FP 0xe
#define __ARM_FP16_FORMAT_IEEE 1
#define __ARM_FP_FENV_ROUNDING 1
#define __ARM_NEON 1
#define __ARM_NEON_FP 0xe
#define __ARM_PCS_AAPCS64 1
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_MINIMAL_ENUM 4
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_WCHAR_T 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for why this feature isn't enabled by default; this is an optional feature not present in the baseline ABI that your compiler targets, i.e. the binaries that your compiler produces are expected to be able to run on devices lacking the CRC feature.

At least for gcc, you can enable this feature with the `-march` modifier `crc`, like this:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - -march=armv8-a+crc < /dev/null | egrep -i '(arm|neon|acle|crc)'
#define __ARM_FEATURE_CRC32 1
#define __ARM_NEON 1
```

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/AArch64-Options.html (or the same page for older gcc versions) for more docs on how to set this.

I guess one could expect `-march=native` to do the same, but that option currently only seems to be implemented for x86 architectures.

Comment: Thanks @mstorsjo. This explains a lot for me; thanks again. How can I get the other defines that should be present, like the other missing features, `__ARM_ARCH` and `__ARM_ACLE`? `__ARM_ACLE` is kind of important because Linaro provides the 4.9 compiler, so `has_include(x)` is not available.

Comment: Wrt `__ARM_ARCH`, apparently gcc has chosen not to include it for aarch64; if `__AARCH64__` is defined, it should be pretty much equivalent to `__ARM_ARCH >= 8`.

As for `__ARM_ACLE`, apparently gcc doesn't set that either. I guess you can just assume that if `__ARM_FEATURE_CRC32` is set, you can include `arm_acle.h` (at least if you are on gcc/clang, and for versions above the one where `__ARM_FEATURE_CRC32` was added, whichever that was - I don't know off-hand).

Comment: Oh, here we go... [GCC Bug 57989 - gcc for ARM defines __ARM_FEATURE_SIMD32, but does provide SIMD32 (ARMv6) intrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57989). From the bug: *"Implementing ACLE is work-in-progress.  It's unfortunate that this define was added before the intrinsics were...."*. It looks like they yanked all the ARM related defines.

Comment: No, that's not the reason why the arm related ones are missing for you (but probably explains why `__ARM_ACLE` is missing). If you do the same `g++ -dM -E - </dev/null | egrep -i '(arm|neon|acle)'` targeting 32 bit arm, you'll get lots (pretty much the same as clang also gives on 64 bit).

On gcc on 64 bit arm/aarch64, some of them are implied (and if unsure, you can check for `__AARCH64__` and have that imply whatever other feature you're looking for, that is either mandatory or irrelevant in aarch64), but some also just seem to be missing.

Comment: I guess the reason for some of it is that gcc treats aarch64 as a completely new architecture, not an extension on top of arm, so they haven't bulk-imported all old defines arm unless they directly have a purpose.

Comment: Yes, these are just missing features in the AArch64 GCC port. `__ARM_ACLE` is not defined as the ACLE support is far from complete, and so claiming to support any particular version through this macro would be misleading.

Comment: Are you sure `arm_acle.h` is getting included in that case? It should be available in gcc 4.9's `arm_acle.h` provided that the feature is enabled (which it should be with those parameters).

Comment: Now open: [Issue 70974: armv8-a+crc does not define __ARM_ACLE](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70974).

Comment: In the code snippet in this SO post, you used `# if defined(__ARM_FEATURE_CRC32) || (__ARM_ACLE >= 200)`, why not just keep using that?