# Is a target-specific variable the proper tool to conditionally set a variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm working on the issue described below. When researching it, the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html), Section 6.11, says:

> Variable values in make are usually global; that is, they are the same
>   regardless of where they are evaluated ... One exception to that is
>   automatic variables (see Automatic Variables).
>
> The other exception is target-specific variable values. This feature
>   allows you to define different values for the same variable, based on
>   the target that make is currently building. As with automatic
>   variables, these values are only available within the context of a
>   target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments).
>
> Set a target-specific variable value like this:
>
> ```
> target … : variable-assignment
> ```
>
> Multiple target values create a target-specific variable value for
>   each member of the target list individually.
>
> ...
>
> There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when
>   you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in
>   effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their
>   prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable
>   with their own target-specific variable value). So, for example, a
>   statement like this:
>
> ```
> prog : CFLAGS = -g
> prog : prog.o foo.o bar.o
> ```
>
> ...

In the context of the GNU Make example above, I need something like:

***Intel machine with SSE4.2***:

```
crc-simd.o: CRC_FLAG = -msse4.2
crc-simd.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CRC_FLAG) -c $<
```

***ARMv8a machine with CRC32***:

```
crc-simd.o: CRC_FLAG = -march=armv8-a+crc
crc-simd.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CRC_FLAG) -c $<
```

I think [Define make variable at rule execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1909188/608639) may be related, but the details are still foggy for me. I'm not sure if it is the keystone or just another alternative.

Is a target-specific variable the proper tool to conditionally set the `CRC_FLAG` variable? If it is, then how do we use it to conditionally set a variable?

If not, then is there a way to assign a value to `CRC_FLAG` only when `crc-simd.o` needs to be built? If there is, then how do we do it?

---

Here's what our GNUmakefile contains. Though ARMv8a is shown, x86/x32/x64 is similar. And we do similar for SSE4.2, NEON, AES, SHA, CLMUL, AVX and BMI.

After the test compile, `CRC_FLAG` will be empty on MIPS, take `-msse4.2` when SSE4.2 is available, and `-march=armv8-a+crc` on ARMv8a. The problem is, it makes recipes like `make clean` take too much time to run. Even building one dirty object file incurs the full wrath of all the compiles. The lag is noticeable.

```
TEMPDIR ?= /tmp
EGREP ?= egrep

IS_ARMV8 ?= $(shell uname -m | $(EGREP) -i -c 'aarch32|aarch64')
...

ifeq ($(IS_ARMV8),1)
  HAS_CRC := $(shell $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -march=armv8-a+crc -o $(TEMPDIR)/t.o -c crc-simd.cpp; echo $$?)
  ifeq ($(HAS_CRC),0)
    CRC_FLAG := -march=armv8-a+crc
  endif
endif
...

# SSE4.2 or ARMv8a available
crc-simd.o : crc-simd.cpp
    $(CXX) $(strip $(CXXFLAGS) $(CRC_FLAG) -c) $<
```

Comment: You seem to have answered your original question, now it sounds like your question should be "how do I stop `make clean` from rebuilding everything", but you haven't provided a complete example.

Comment: Thanks @user657267. *"how do I stop make clean from rebuilding everything"* - there's actually more rules that need to avoid building everything. Hence the reason I was trying to be surgical about populating `CRC_FLAG`. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _incurs the full wrath of all the compiles_.  All what compiles?  You mean, the `HAS_CRC := $(shell $(CXX) ...)` compiles?  I don't see why all of them would run; wouldn't only the one compile for this particular value of `IS_...` run?

Comment: @MadScientist - If I need to build `foo.o` and `bar.o`, they will cause the `HAS_CRC` gear to operate because I don't know how to say, *"Only evaluate the `HAS_CRC` and only set the value for `CRC_FLAG` variable when building `crc-simd.o`"*.

Comment: OK, but it only runs once per invocation of make, and only one of them runs, correct?  So, it's basically one extra compilation per invocation of make, right?  I get that this could be annoying but I'm trying to understand your comments about _incurs the full wrath of all compiles_.

Comment: @MadScientist - Regarding the wrath of the compiler, we don't use Autotools, so we configure on the fly with GNUmakefile. `CRC_FLAG` invokes the compiler to see if `-msse4.2` or `-march=armv8-a+crc` is consumed by the compiler. Now, multiply that by 12 to 24 for other features. And do it on a CubieTruck or BeagleBoard. It takes make 5 minutes to start building the stuff on CubieTruck or BeagleBoard. The 5 minute penalty is even incurred by `foo.o` and `bar.o`, which don't use any of the features.

Comment: OK but I assume you're not testing for sse4.2 on ARM and not testing for armv8-a+crc on Intel, right?  You only test for the options that could exist based on the `IS_...` option obtained from `uname -m`?  It also seems like you could probably avoid lots of invocations of `uname -m`; why not just run it one time then do the rest of the testing in the makefile?  It would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need this flag for a single .o file like `crc-simd.o`, then why use `:=` in the assignment of `CRC_FLAG`?  If you use `=` instead then it won't be expanded until it's used and if you only use it once it will only be expanded once.

Something like:

```
ifeq ($(IS_ARMV8),1)
  CRC_FLAG = $(shell $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -march=armv8-a+crc -o $(TEMPDIR)/t.o -c crc-simd.cpp 2>/dev/null && printf %s -march=armv8-a+crc)
endif

# SSE4.2 or ARMv8a available
crc-simd.o : crc-simd.cpp
        $(CXX) $(strip $(CXXFLAGS) $(CRC_FLAG) -c) $<
```

This still compiles the file twice; it seems like there should be a faster way to determine if that flag is supported but anyway.

Comment: *" it seems like there should be a faster way to determine if that flag is supported but anyway..."* - Lol, yeah I know what you mean. The problem is mostly ARM targets. GCC and Clang are pretty f'd up when it comes to a native build. They act like they are ARMv6 on Aarch64, except they generate code for Aarch64. Otherwise, GCC advertises nothing. See, for example, [Why is __ARM_FEATURE_CRC32 not being defined by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37066261/608639)

Comment: So, the output of `gcc -march=armv8-a --target-help` doesn't show the `crc` extension when it's available and not when it isn't available?

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist. I did not see anything interesting. No hits like crc, aes, sha, pmull, asimd. Here's the Pastebin, if interested: [`gcc -march=armv8-a --target-help`](https://pastebin.com/0tgWisfu).

Comment: I believe you answered this question: *"If not, then is there a way to assign a value to CRC_FLAG only when crc-simd.o needs to be built? If there is, then how do we do it?"* Is that correct (you answered it)?

Comment: That is the question I was answering, yes.  If you use a recursive variable assignment then the value won't be expanded when the variable is defined; instead it's expanded when the variable is used.  If the variable is only used one time in the recipe for the `crc-simd.o` target then it will be expanded only when that target is built.

Comment: Ack, thanks. Your suggestion about avoiding the compiles worked really well. I'm checking the preprocessor for defines in most cases; see [`GNUmakefile`](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile#L309) (ARMv8) and [`GNUmakefile`](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile#L201) (Intel).

Comment: You probably want to jot a comment to yourself (or some future person) about why this is a recursive variable assignment.  The rule of thumb for variables containing `$(shell ...)` functions is always use simple variables (`:=`) so documenting why that is not done here would be wise.  Cheers!